# Parsing SQL data via System.Data

Tags: python, .net, wpf, ironpython

I am currently writing an application in IronPython/WPF and will heavily utilize SQL select and set statements during production.

I have successfully connected to the server and can grab the data I wish via queries. However I am having issues parsing the response data. See below code

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import *

query = 'sqlquery'

conn = SqlClient.SqlConnection(--sql connection properties--)
conn.Open()

result = SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn)
data = result.ExecuteReader()

while data.Read():
    print(data[0])

data.Close()
conn.Close()
```

The issue I am having is `print(data[0])` is required to print any of the SQL response, a simple print(data) returns:

`<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader object at 0x00000000000002FF [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader]>`

However a `print(data[0])` only returns the index of the row in SQL, `[1]` the next column etc etc.

I would like to access all data from the row (where rows can be variable lengths, different queries etc)

How could I get this to work?

**EDIT:**

I have successfully extracted all data from one row of the response with the following code;

```
for i in range(1, data.FieldCount):
     print(data.GetName(i))
     print(data.GetValue(i))
```

Just need to determine how to perform this iteration over all returned rows so I can pass it to a dict/datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me.

Utilizing the SqlAdapter and Datasets to store/view data later as required

```
def getdataSet(self, query):
        conn = SqlClient.SqlConnection(---sql cred---))
        conn.Open()

        result = SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn)
        data = SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(result)

        ds = DataSet()
        data.Fill(ds)

        return ds

def main(self):
        ds = self.getdataSet("query")

        self.maindataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView
```